# MySQL Referencing New and Old Values in Update Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I would like to create a join where I can update a field depending on the new and old values of a field in another table. For example:

```
UPDATE
    table1,
    table2
SET
    table1.field1 = newDate
    table2.field2 = table1.field1 -- The NEW date I am setting above in field1 ^
WHERE
    table2.field2 = table1.field1 -- The OLD date currently set in table1.field1
```

Is this possible? I tried using `new` and `old` clauses but doesn't work.

**Edit**
If you are so kind as to vote down the question for no reason. Please contribute somehow...

Comment: So why do you not want to do table2.field2=newDate?

Comment: I am trying to make the query as automatic as possible. If I do `SET table2.field2 = newDate` I am writing redundantly which is what I want to avoid. If you also notice, I would have to repeat the old date as well in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Could I suggest that you phrase the query as:

```
UPDATE table1 JOIN
       table2
       ON table2.field2 = table1.field1
    SET table1.field1 = newDate,
        table2.field2 = newDate
```

It seems to remove the ambiguity that is causing your confusion.

EDIT:

You seem to have this great desire to only reference `newDate` once.  You can do so with a subquery:

```
UPDATE table1 JOIN
       table2
       ON table2.field2 = table1.field1 CROSS JOIN
       (select @newDate as newDate) vars
    SET table1.field1 = vars.newDate,
        table2.field2 = vars.newDate;
```

I am unclear as to the motive, but this provides a mechanism for only referring to it once.

If it help you understand updates, think about how they work according to the SQL standard.  The `update` does not take place until after the values are committed to the database.  That is, there are no "new" values in the table while the `update` is being processed.  MySQL does not necessarily behave this way, but that is a good model for how `update` works.

Comment: will `table2.field2 = table1.field1` reference the new field to be updated or the one currently on the table. Also, how can it be set so the where clause references the old value already set in `table1.field1`?

Comment: @user3704920 . . . If references the old value.  The `join` brings the data together for the update, so it is logically executed before the update.

Comment: so I guess the question is, can the new data be referenced?

Comment: the point is I constantly run queries all day, so the less input the more efficient I will be, plus less margin for error by limiting input. Could you perhaps explain that last query where the new data is referenced?